# Launch files not copied into share folder by catkin_make

Tags: roslaunch, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My launch-files do not get placed into the devel/share folder also I state inside CMakeLists.txt. The 4 files are inside the src//launch folder.

```
   # install the launch files
     install(DIRECTORY launch/
        DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}/launch)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225484/launch-files-not-copied-into-share-folder-by-catkin_make/) by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on ROS Answers with karma: 748 on 2016-01-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2016-01-31**:
Try removing the last "/" in the install line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Launch files are not copied into the devel folder.
Using the install tag, they are installed in the respective folder in `install`, if you do a `catkin_make install`

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on 2016-02-01**:
I see: `catkin_make install` triggers `install` inside CMakeList. Still the question how to get them into devel?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-02-02**:
you don't need them in `devel`. You use those from `src`, if you source `devel/setup.bash`.